# Previewing PDF documents in Thunderbird: images load very slowly

Tags: pdf, thunderbird

Ubuntu 22.04.3LTS Desktop

Thunderbird 102.13.0 64 bit

32GB RAM

I receive PDFs as email attachment frequently.
I'd set up Thunderbird to manage these as 'Preview in Thunderbird'.
I've found colour pages take a very long time to display in the preview tab (eg 30 seconds for each page of a pdf with a detailed colour picture). I'm not talking about huge files - eg 4MB. I thought it might be my graphics card isn't up to it, but when I save the pdf, I can open in document viewer and display the full document with virtually no lag.

I can change Thunderbird to default to open with Document viewer instead, but it's quite slick to have the document open in a separate tab - is there any way to make pdf documents preview faster in Thunderbird?

Graphics card: Asus GeForce 1030, using Nvidia driver 535 (I changed to this from Nouveau yesterday - before I noticed that opening using pdf viewer was much faster - to see if it made any difference: little or no change).

Thanks!